# Google Sheets App Scripts that adds grid lines to first seven columns where the first row in that column is not empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can anyone help me with a script that adds gridlines to the first seven columns of a row if the first column in that row is not empty?

Here is the code I'm using - grabbed from an old response to a different question on here that I can't find again. I need to change it from adding borders to all cells that are not empty to the behavior I mentioned above.

```
 var menu = [{name: "Draw Borders", functionName: "borders"}];
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Borders", menu);
}

function borders() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Tab_Name').getDataRange();
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Tab_Name').getRange("B50:H200")
  cell.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 2; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      
        range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
      }
    }
 
  }
```

Edit - I found the original question I pulled that code from:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/84848/automatically-add-borders-around-nonempty-cells
From the response by User Hassan Almaateeq

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `the first instance that a row is empty at column 1`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: Can you provide the code you are working on and clarify what is the outcome you expect, either via screenshots or through a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information)?

Comment: Hello. The outcome I'm looking for is:  If the first cell of a row is not empty, add gridlines to the first seven columns of that row. For instance, if A1 is not empty, add gridlines to A1:A7, if B1 is not empty, add gridlines to B1:B7, etc. Does that clarify?

Comment: @Tanaike I've also added the code I'm working with so far

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information． Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your question. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample input and output situation as the images? By this, I would like to try to confirm your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You want to set borders to columns B-H in rows where column A is empty.

#### Solution:

In this case, you can do the following:

- Get a range with first 8 columns and the desired rows (from 50 to 200 in the sample below).
- Retrieve the corresponding values and iterate through them, for example with a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop.
- For each row, check if the first value in the array (column A) is an empty string, and set border for that row with that's the case, **setting a new range that includes columns `B-H` but just that specific row**.

#### Code snippet:

```
function borders() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Tab_Name');
  var firstRow = 50; // Change according to your preferences
  var lastRow = 200; // Change according to your preferences
  var numRows = lastRow - firstRow + 1;
  var lastCol = 8;
  var range = sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, numRows, lastCol);
  range.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
  var firstCol = 2;
  var numCols = lastCol - firstCol + 1;
  var values = range.getValues();
  values.forEach((row,i) => {
    if (row[0] !== "") {
      sheet.getRange(firstRow + i, firstCol, 1, numCols)
           .setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
    }
  });
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. I just realized I didn't copy the first line defining an onOpen function into my question.  I apologize. Also, is it possible to edit this so that instead of saving the tab name in the variable sheet,  it just applies to whatever tab is open when you run it?  I add tab to the spreadsheets frequently and would like this to work on all of them.  Again, thank you.

Comment: Nevermind, I sorted that out by just changing the sheet variable to SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()